# How many unlucky numbers in segment [a;b]?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

Some numbers are called unlucky if their decimal representation contain the number `5`.

For example: `123456`, `245`, `1555` are unlucky numbers and `111`, `123`, `147` are not unlucky numbers.

How many unlucky numbers are there in segment `[a:b]`?, where `1 < a < b`.

For example `a = 1`, `b = 17` , we have the result is `2`. Because, there are only `5`, `15`.

> This is my try: I call `f(a)` is the amount of unlucky numbers in segment `[1;a]`, then we have `f(a+1)` is the the amount of unlucky numbers in segment `[1;a+1]`, so we have: `f(a+1)=f(a)` if `a+1` is not unlucky number and `f(a+1)=f(a)+1` if a+1 is unlucky number. My problem is to compute `f(a)` with `O(log(n))`, but I can't come to good solution!

Comment: Could you format your question better?  The `$` symbols are rather irritating.  StackOverflow doesn't support LaTeX.

Comment: @Bernard doesn't it somehow support it in the quoted text ? I think I remember using latex symbols a couple of times, but I may be wrong

Comment: @m.raynal I'm using a browser on my desktop now, and I sure see lots of '$' symbols littered around the question.  Maybe you were thinking of the mathematics stack exchange site?

Comment: Yep, probably the math and the tex stack exchange, my memory is playing games with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easilly solved in O(log N) time using dynamic programming known as "dp on digits"

First note that instead of calculating unlucky numbers in inertval `[L,R]` we can instead define some function
`f(X)` that calculates unlucky numbers in interval `[0,x]`, so unlucky numbers in interval `[L,R]`
can be calculated as `f(R) - f(L-1)`

Creating function `f()` is kinda straightforward, we have our state as `dp[pos][ls][unlucky]` where:

- `pos` - current digit we are trying to fill
- `ls` - just a flag that saysif our prefix matches the limit of how high we can go
- `unlucky` - another flag that says if our number is already unlucky or not

Then we can do simple recursion expansion digit by digits + memoization.

Sample code (C++11) :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long

ll dp[51][2][2];
ll digits[51];
int amount_of_digits;

ll solve(ll pos, ll ls, ll unlucky)
{
    if(pos >= amount_of_digits)return unlucky;
    if(dp[pos][ls][unlucky]!=-1)return dp[pos][ls][unlucky];

    dp[pos][ls][unlucky]=0;

    for(int i=0; i<=(ls ? 9 : digits[pos]); i++) //next digit
        dp[pos][ls][unlucky]+=solve(pos+1,ls | (i<digits[pos]), unlucky | (i==5));

    return dp[pos][ls][unlucky];
}

ll f(ll x)
{
    string s = to_string(x);
    amount_of_digits = s.size();

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
        digits[i] = s[i]-'0';

    memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp);
    return solve(0,0,0);
}

ll calc_interval(ll L, ll R)
{
    return f(R) - f(L-1);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<calc_interval(2,17);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I won't give you the full solution, but I'll give you a hint that should point you in the correct direction.  You need to apply some mathematics (permutation & combination) knowledge to this problem.

Suppose you want to find the number of *unlucky* numbers in [0, 12345).  With some math, you can calculate the number of such numbers in [0, 10000) in O(1).  Then, you could calculate the number of such numbers in [10000, 12000) in O(1).  Then do it for [12000, 12300).  Now if you see where we're going...

To find the number of unlucky numbers in [a, b], we can simply calculate the number of unlucky numbers in [0, a) and the number of unlucky numbers in [0, b+1).

Note: You don't actually need to calculate the number of unlucky numbers in [0, 10000) in O(1).  It also suffices to find a way to calculate the number of unlucky numbers in [0, 10000) *from the number of unlucky numbers in [10000, 12000)* in O(1).